Firebase Auth Twitter immediately redirecting back to login page
I'm trying to implement firebase oAuth providers into my next.js 14 app.  I have Google, Microsoft, and Yahoo logins all working fine.  But when I try to login with Twitter, I just get redirected back to my app's login page immediately without being shown the consent screen.
In the twitter developer portal, I've created a project, I've set the redirect url correctly, and I've obtained the client ID and client secret for oAuth 1.0a.  From what I've read, oAuth 1.0a is the version that firebase uses for Twitter.  In firebase, I've enable Twitter as a sign-in provider and supplied the credentials that I've obtained from Twitters developer portal.
Here's is all the relevant code
firebase-config.js
import { initializeApp, getApp, getApps } from "firebase/app";
import {
  getAuth,
  TwitterAuthProvider,
  OAuthProvider,
  GoogleAuthProvider,
} from "firebase/auth";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MESSING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
};

const app = getApps().length > 0 ? getApp() : initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

//OAuth Providers
const yahooProvider = new OAuthProvider("yahoo.com");
const microsoftProvider = new OAuthProvider("microsoft.com");
const twitterProvider = new TwitterAuthProvider();
const googleProvider = new GoogleAuthProvider();

export const auth = getAuth(app);

export { googleProvider, yahooProvider, twitterProvider, microsoftProvider };

LoginCard.tsx
"use client";
import React from "react";
import Image from "next/image";
import { FaYahoo, FaTwitter, FaApple } from "react-icons/fa";
import { FcGoogle } from "react-icons/fc";
import {
  handleYahoo,
  handleGoogle,
  handleTwitter,
  handleMicrosoft,
} from "../../../lib/loginHandlers";
import { auth } from "../../../lib/firebase-config";
import { signOut } from "firebase/auth";
type Props = {
  portalName: string;
  redirectPortalName: string;
};

const signOutUser = () => {
  signOut(auth);
  console.log("fired sign out method");
};

const signInOptions = [
  { name: "Yahoo", icon: <FaYahoo />, color: "#553E93", onClick: handleYahoo },
  {
    name: "Google",
    icon: <FcGoogle />,
    onClick: handleGoogle,
    color: "#71A6FF",
  },
  {
    name: "Twitter",
    icon: <FaTwitter />,
    color: "#019AD6",
    onClick: handleTwitter,
  },
  { name: "Apple", icon: <FaApple />, color: "rgba(0,0,0,1)" },
  {
    name: "Microsoft",
    icon: (
      <Image
        src="/images/microsoft.png"
        width={16}
        height={16}
        alt="microsoft Logo"
      />
    ),
    color: "#2C2C2E",
    onClick: handleMicrosoft,
  },
];

export default function LoginCard({ portalName, redirectPortalName }: Props) {
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center rounded-xl p-3 md:border-2 md:border-gray-200 md:px-10 md:py-10 md:shadow-2xl">
      <h1 className="mb-10 mt-2 border-b-4 border-golden font-playfair text-4xl">
        Login
      </h1>
      <h2 className="mb-10 text-xl font-light">{portalName}</h2>

      {signInOptions.map((provider) => (
        <button
          onClick={provider.onClick}
          key={provider.name}
          style={{ backgroundColor: `${provider.color}` }}
          className="mb-3 min-w-[100%] rounded-xl border border-gray-200 p-3 text-white transition-all duration-150 hover:opacity-75"
        >
          <span className="mr-2 inline-block">{provider.icon}</span> Sign in
          with {provider.name}
        </button>
      ))}
      <span className="mt-8 text-center">
        Looking for the{" "}
        <a
          className="text-link transition-all duration-150 hover:text-linkHover"
          href=""
        >
          {redirectPortalName}
        </a>
        ?
      </span>
      <button onClick={signOutUser}>Sign Out</button>
    </div>
  );
}

loginHandlers.ts
import { signInWithRedirect } from "firebase/auth";
import {
  yahooProvider,
  googleProvider,
  twitterProvider,
  microsoftProvider,
  auth,
} from "./firebase-config";


export const handleTwitter = async () => {
  console.log("Twitter fired");
  const result = await signInWithRedirect(auth, twitterProvider);
  console.log(result);
};

export const handleGoogle = async () => {
  console.log("Google fired");
  const result = await signInWithRedirect(auth, googleProvider);
  console.log(result);
};

export const handleYahoo = async () => {
  console.log("Yahoo fired");
  const result = await signInWithRedirect(auth, yahooProvider);
  console.log(result);
};


export const handleMicrosoft = async () => {
  console.log("Microsoft fired");
  const result = await signInWithRedirect(auth, microsoftProvider);
  console.log(result);
};

Please let me know if there's something obvious that I'm missing or if I didn't provide enough information, because I most likely have.
I was facing an issue with Google oAuth immediately redirecting back to my login page without showing the consent screen and that was caused by Firefox not allowing third-party cookies.  However, I'm pretty sure what's happening with the Twitter login is being cause by the browser not allowing third-party cookies.  I've tested it in different browsers and made sure tracking protection was disabled and I still just get redirected back to the login page of my app immediately.
